# How to identify the Nth repetition of an element in a string?

Tags: r, regex, tidyr, stringr

## Packages

```
library(tidyverse)
```

## My data

```
str <- tibble(value = c("var_imp_01_prevalence",
                        "var_imp_MeanDecreaseGini_variance_pairwise_distance",
                        "var_imp_06_extinction_rate"))
str
  value                  
  <chr>                  
1 var_imp_01_prevalence  
2 var_imp_MeanDecreaseGini_variance_pairwise_distance
3 var_imp_06_extinction_rate
```

## What I want as output

```
  a        b            
  <chr>    <chr>        
1 var_imp_01 prevalence
2 var_imp_MeanDecreaseGini variance_pairwise_distance
3 var_imp_06 extinction_rate
```

## Details

So, basically I want to use the tidyr::separate function to find the third '_' and separate my columns.

Comment: Would finding the final underscore work? That is probably easier.

Comment: Not really, the real data has more underscores after

Comment: Split on [`^[^_]*_[^_]*_[^_]*\K_` and pass the parameter `perl=T`](https://tio.run/##K/r/v0LBRlchWUOpLLEoPjO3IN7AML6gKLUsMSc1LzlVSYeLEy6TmJScgkvOwMgpvjgzPS8xR0mTq7ikqLggJ7NEo0JHQSkuOi4@ViseiYyJ8Y5X0lEoSC3KsQ3R/P8fAA)

Comment: `str %>% extract(value, into = c("a", "b"), regex = "(.*_.*_.*)_(.*)")`?

Comment: A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1: this did not worked, it is separeting the data based on the last _ in the real data.

Comment: ctwheels: I would like to use the stringr::separate function... can I pass the parameter perl=T to it?

Comment: Can you have a data that represents what you have?

Comment: @BrunoVilela I may be mistaken, but I don't think the `stringr` package has a method of `separate`. I'm pretty sure it's part of `tidyr`? So I don't think what you're asking is possible.

Comment: Just changed the data to something closer to the real data

Comment: @ctwheels correct, just changed. But the question is still the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `extract`, it could be done e.g. this way. The `^` is important for not matching based on the last `_`

```
str %>% extract(value, into = c("a", "b"), regex = "^([^_]*_[^_]*_[^_*]*)_(.*)")

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  a                        b                         
* <chr>                    <chr>                     
1 var_imp_01               prevalence                
2 var_imp_MeanDecreaseGini variance_pairwise_distance
3 var_imp_06               extinction_rate
```

Comment: That worked, thanks! Another question would be if it is possible to simplify the regex in order to just state the number of repetitions, just in case someone have to match the 50th instead of the 3rd.

Comment: Glad it helped! You can repeat the main pattern (`[^_]*_`) as often as you want by putting it in its own group. Since you then have one group too much, you simply make the inner group non-capturing with `?:`. E.g., you could use this regex instead `^((?:[^_]*_){3})(.*)`.. probably also more intuitive since it includes the `3`. Only downside is you will have the `_` at the end of your matches for `a`, but that can be removed with one more line.

Answer (score 1):

```
str%>%mutate(value=sub("((_.*?){3})","\\1SPLIT",value))%>%separate(value,c("a","b"),"_SPLIT")
# A tibble: 3 x 2
                         a                          b
*                    <chr>                      <chr>
1               var_imp_01                 prevalence
2 var_imp_MeanDecreaseGini variance_pairwise_distance
3               var_imp_06            extinction_rate
```

Comment: That is a good solution, wondering if the regex could go direct in the separate function, to avoid the mutate code.

Comment: Will look into that. Its just

Answer (score 0):

This is a job for `regex`, try to use the following code:

```
# For 'a' 
a <- sub("(^.*)_...", "\\1", str[1]) # [1] "var_imp_01valence"

# For 'b'
b <- sub("^.*_(...)", "\\1", str[1]) # [1] "prevalence"
```

Im not an expert in `regex` but at least do the job for your example.

Hope this can help.

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to use the tidyr package.